# How to slice just the information that I need in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file like that:

phone-number name_of_a_person, like:

```
123-4555-5555 harry

123-4555-5555 Rony

123-4555-5555 Hermione

123-4555-5555 harry

123-4555-5555 hermione
```

The code that I have so far is this:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
     data = f.read().split()
```

It gives me a list of the data but what I need is to grab the first 3 digits and the name and put it in a new file like this:

```
123 harry

123 Rony

123 Hermione
```

The problem is that I cant see how I can manipulate the data in the list to achieve that because I don't need to slice the names, just the numbers.

Comment: is the data that you have in old file having new line `\n` after each record ?

Comment: Yes, there is a \n

Comment: I have updated my answer as per new line `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try read from one file and refine data and write to another file, see below example.

```
with open('old_file.txt', 'r') as stream:
    lines = stream.readlines()  # read line as list

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as wr:
for line in lines:
    if not line == '\n':   # removing new line '\n' from lines
        wr.write(line.split()[0][:3]+ ' ' + line.split()[1]+'\n')  # use split and slice while writing
```

`new_file.txt` content:

```
123 harry
123 Rony
123 Hermione
123 harry
123 hermione
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you need

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.rstrip() == '':
            data = line.split(' ')
            print(data[0][0:3],data[1])
```

Comment: It gives me: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @GratefullyDead do you have the empty lines in your file?

Comment: I do have a \n in the file after each line.

Comment: @GratefullyDead I was missing the code to skip `\n` only lines